# Rewriting a for loop to an sapply taking into account NA's

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, sapply

I would like to have R calculate the `netincome` for a certain amount of `Income`:

```
panelID = c(1:50)   
year= c(2001:2010)
country = "NLD"
n <- 2
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(panelID = rep(sample(panelID), each = n),
                 country = rep(sample(country, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                 year = c(replicate(length(panelID), sample(year, n))),
                 some_NA = sample(0:5, 6),                                             
                 some_NA_factor = sample(0:5, 6),         
                 norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                 Income = round(rnorm(10,10,10),2),
                 Happiness = sample(10,10),
                 Sex = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                 Age = sample(100,100),
                 Educ = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2))        
DT [, uniqueID := .I]                                                         # Creates a unique ID     
DT[DT == 0] <- NA 
DT$Income[DT$Income < 0] <- NA 
DT <- as.data.frame(DT)
```

Now, the tax needs to be calculated as follows:

For the first five years (2001-2005), Income < 20 = 25%, Income >20 == 50%

For the second five years (2006-2010), Income < 15 = 20%, Income >20 == 45%

I tried to write it as follows:

```
for (i in DT$Income) {
    if (DT$Income[i] < 20 & DT$year[i] < 2006) {
        DT$netincome[i] <- DT$Income[i] - (DT$Income[i]*0.25)
    } else if (DT$Income[i] > 20 & DT$year[i] < 2006) {
        DT$netincome[i] <- DT$Income[i] - (20*0.25) - ((DT$Income[i]-20)*0.5)
    } else if (DT$Income[i] < 15 & DT$year[i] > 2005) {
        DT$netincome[i] <- DT$Income[i] - (DT$Income[i]*0.20)
    } else if (DT$Income[i] > 15 & DT$year[i] > 2005) {
        DT$netincome[i] <- DT$Income[i] - (15*0.20) - ((DT$Income[i]-15)*0.45)
    } 
    }
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "netincome", value = c(NA, NA, NA,  : 
  replacement has 15 rows, data has 100
```

In addition, I would really like to rewrite this in a cleaner way with `sapply` but I am struggling with how.

Comment: `sapply` loses the benefit of vectorization. All your computations are on vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
DT[Income < 0,Income:= NA] # better use this construction
DT[,.(netincome = case_when(Income < 20 & year < 2006 ~ Income - 0.25 * Income,
                            Income > 20 & year < 2006 ~ Income - 20 * 0.25 - 0.5 * (Income - 20),
                            Income < 15 & year > 2005 ~ Income - 0.2 * Income,
                            Income > 15 & year > 2005 ~ Income - 15*0.2 - 0.45 * (Income - 15)))]
```

This would be much easier if you use consistent column name (best practice tolower). And try not to use names like DT. DT stands for one of a well used package in R, and it's a bit confusing. And in future version of data.table there would be an fcase, which faster then case_when

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in base R, you don't need to use `sapply`; you can just nest a few `ifelse` statements.

```
DT$netincome <- with(DT, ifelse(year < 2006 & Income < 20, Income - (Income * 0.25),
  ifelse(year < 2006 & Income > 20, Income - (20 * 0.25) - ((Income - 20)* 0.5),
  ifelse(Income < 15, Income - (Income * 0.20), Income - (15 * 0.20) - ((Income - 15) * 0.45) ))))
```

Summary of resulting column. Does this match your expected output?

```
> summary(DT$netincome)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  4.372   4.710  11.053  11.614  14.881  27.076      20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
DT%>%
  mutate(netincome = case_when(Income < 20 & year < 2006 ~ Income - 0.25 * Income,
                               Income > 20 & year < 2006 ~ Income - 20*0.25 - 0.5*(Income-20),
                               Income < 15 & year > 2005 ~ Income -0.2*Income,
                               Income > 15 & year > 2005 ~ Income - 15*0.2 - 0.45*(Income-15))
```

If you like dplyr approach :), you also can use %<>% this operator. Or if you don't want new column you may switch to summarize

Comment: please combine your answers into one, unless you think it is really necessary to make in two separate ones

Comment: Hm, i think it would be better to separate data.table and dplyr approaches.